# How to broadcast a web whiteboard to the particular group using SignalR

Tags: signalr

Am having a web whiteboard, which was built using javascript and also am having a set of predefined users in a particular group, i have to broadcast it using a SignalR but i dont have any idea about it.
So please help me to find a solution

Answer (score 0):

You should probably start here  https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1100425/SignalR-with-ASP-NET-One-to-one-and-Group-Chat-wit

What you are looking for is similar to a one to one chat in that you are only sending data to specific users.

At a high level: Assign people a unique username and link it to their session ID when they connect. When you broadcast something you'll check your list of who to send it to vs who's online and send it to those who are online.

Comment: Thanks MickeyM, I have tried all these things, i already created private and group chat using Signalr. But still am facing issue in broadcasting the whiteboard.